# What is the difference between these two recursive approaches

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I have two versions of the same algorithm which recursively find the minimum element in a linked list. One algorithm first checks whether the end of the list has been reached and if so, returns that element then checks to see whether the current element (head of the list) is less then the current min from the recursive call. If the current element is greater, the current min (found by the recursive call) is returned.

The other algorithm does something only slightly different in that, after the check for the base case, it stores the recursive call in a temp variable and then uses temp to do the comparison with the current list element.

I found the recurrence for the first approach to be:

> T(n) = 1T(n-1) + O(1)

(which I'm not entirely sure about)

What I can't figure out is what would be the difference in the recurrence for the second algorithm as they seem to be doing the same thing. Does the recursive call being stored in the temp variable add extra work for the recurrence?

The pseudocode for both algorithms is below:

***First approach***

```
function min_list_1(L) // L is a non-empty list of numbers
    if has_only_one_element(L): return L.head
    if L.head < min_list_1(L.next): return L.head
    else:
        return min_list_1(L.next)
```

***Second approach***

```
function min_list_2(L) // L is a non-empty list of numbers
    if has_only_one_element(L): return L.head
    temp = min_list_2(L.next)
    if L.head < temp: return L.head
    else:
        return temp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one will make the recursive call twice for most cases (when L.head isn't the smallest found): once to evaluate the condition, and a second time to return the new value.  This causes a 2^n complexity.  Using **temp** keeps it linear.

Comment: So I've been running the first algorithm line by line (in Visual Studio) and I haven't been able to figure out what the second recursive call in the else statement is being used for. I see in the debugger that its essentially just running back through all of the same comparisons that have been previously been done so in which case is it actually doing new work?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 The worst case is when the list is sorted in the descending order

Comment: @undermind Right, but how is the second recursive call in the first algorithm contributing to the solution of the problem?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 On each step of the recursion you make 2 calls to `min_list_1()`. So on the first step you'll make 2 calls in total, on second - 4, on third - 8 and so on. You can count the total number of calls to `min_list_1()` by some global counter.

Comment: @undermind Sorry maybe I'm not clearly expressing my point of confusion. I understand the complexity of the two recursive calls at each step but what I'm confused about is why the second recursive call is necessary in finding the min. The second algorithm only has one recursive call to step through the list linearly (which is the way I intuitively think of the max/min problem). So why would the second recursive call ever be needed?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 where is the source of first snippet? I do not think the second call is needed as you say

Comment: @undermind This is all that was given, the problem was to differentiate between the two versions of the algorithm

Comment: @shole Sorry the previous comment was directed at you

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 no problem, indeed "using memory to store the result of recursion so that we do not have to recalculate them" has a very famous technique named "Dynamic Programming", which is "recursion + memorization". You can see more about it

Comment: The extra call adds nothing to the algorithm; it duplicates exactly the work of the first call.  The barely-hidden cognitive problem is that we humans tend to abstract the entire call as a symbol; some people won't notice at first that that second appearance of **min_list_1(L.next)** replicates the effort of the first one -- each of which is notably more than **min_list_2** would do.

Comment: Oh ok, so at each step for the first (naive) algorithm, the amount of work done locally is 2^n because each recursive call for when the min is not found makes two additional recursive calls.

Comment: Exactly: the number of calls doubles at each level.  In comparison, the work done locally in the other routine is 1^n, which reduces to O(1) per level.

Comment: So then my recurrences are really:  ***T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(2^n)***  and               ***T(n) = 1T(n-1) + O(1)***

Comment: I think so.  We weren't *quite* this detailed when I learned complexity as part of my foundations class, so I'm not the best person to review your final answer.

Answer (score 1):

On top of **loremIpsum1771**'s answer, I give you a simple analogy here:

```js
for(int i=0; i< strlen(s); i++){
     ...
}
     
     
     vs
     
for(int i=0, len=strlen(s); i<len; i++){
     ...
}
```

Which one is faster and why?

The first one is much slower and the reason is exactly the same with your OP, **you call something every time / many times when you can indeed precompute once**